# Why using larger bitmaps cause more memory in my game?

Tags: android, memory-management

My game's initial heap was 12 Mb.now after loading a bitmap of size 1280*800 heap size has increased to 22 Mb.My game isn't even complete yet.just some basic setups.I am afraid memory will reach to a great extent this way.
Also I was playing some game yesterday,it was also using so many diff images of same size but its size was only 20 Mb.how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sprite sheets to keep memory usage down.

[What is a sprite sheet?](http://www.codeandweb.com/what-is-a-sprite-sheet)

Comment: Thank You.That's kind of ans I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

Why does using larger bitmaps require more memory?  Because *larger bitmaps are larger*.  There's more data to store.

You've reached the point of having a tautology....

Comment: But how does  games like nfs or temple run run while causing heap of ~50 or 60 mb?

Comment: @Mukul every pixel cost 8 byte (if I remember correctly), now do the math and you see the picture.